# How to put two parameter in DATA ( Ajax,jquery)?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to put to parameter in DATA , how can I do this ?

I try that , but that did'nt work :

```
 data: dataString + form_data ,
```

My complete code:

```
        $(".edit_tr").click(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
$("#first_"+ID).hide();
$("#last_"+ID).hide();
$("#first_input_"+ID).show();
$("#last_input_"+ID).show();
}).change(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var first=$("#first_input_"+ID).val();
var last=$("#last_input_"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&firstname='+first+'&lastname='+last;
$("#first_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />');


if(first.length && last.length>0)


{
var form_data = {
    ci_csrf_token: $.cookie("ci_csrf_token"),

}

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:'http://' + document.domain + '/school/teachers/editscore/',
//data: dataString,
data: form_data,


//cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {

        $("#first_"+ID).html(first);
        $("#last_"+ID).html(last);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass data as a json object

```
var form_data = '&ci_csrf_token='+ $.cookie("ci_csrf_token");

    };
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:'http://' + document.domain + '/school/teachers/editscore/',
//data: dataString,
data: dataString + form_data,
processData: false,
//cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {

        $("#first_"+ID).html(first);
        $("#last_"+ID).html(last);
        }
});
```

Comment: wont work , i got this error The action you have requested is not allowed. ( because of csrf protection )  ,    the  var  form_data don't pass

Thx for the reply

Comment: Make sure the json is well formed. Take a look at processData property of JQuery AJAX it might give you some idea in regards to this.

Comment: Thx...  I try  to proccesData but nothing pass......I updated my  code , I forgot the first part of my code in my first post....

Comment: @user - I have edited my answer based on your updates to the question pelase try it.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to concatenate a string and a Json literal and store it in a parameter that accepts Json.

Instead, if you want to pass two different things to the server, store it as two different properties in the Json:

```
var form_data = {
    ci_csrf_token: $.cookie("ci_csrf_token"),
    string: "dataString" 
}; 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'http://' + document.domain + '/school/teachers/editscore/',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#first_"+ID).html(first);
        $("#last_"+ID).html(last);
    } });
```

You can always then just perform the concatenation on the server side of your application once you have each property.

Comment: wont work , my  var dataSting don't pass, I updated my code , I forgot to put the first part of my code , 

Thx for the reply

Answer (score 0):

```
data: dataString + form_data ,
```

should work, i was struggling to fully understand your question.